# Angular 2 dependency injection error on NgFor in dynamically created component

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I've dynamically created an Angular 2 component using [`DynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982258/angular-2-dynamic-template-variable-names-for-dynamiccomponentloader#), and am trying to give it a useful template (involving NgFor), but this is somehow yielding me a '`DI exception`' dependency injection error.

I had already injected NgFor itself though, so specifically now it gave me a `No provider for IterableDiffers! (NgFor -> IterableDiffers)`. So I injected that, which got me to a `No provider for Array! (NgFor -> IterableDiffers -> Array)`. At this point I got stumped; Array is a base type rather than something part of Angular, and somehow trying to similarly inject it did not work (error: Array is a generic; must specificy some sub-type). I'm confused but I'd be surprised if basic types suddenly required injection.

I made a Plunker to recreate my issue [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xu4QdFLaf5b1ld2pxKNq?p=preview). Interestingly on Plunker the DI exception turned out as `No provider for e! (e -> e)` instead. Not sure why the difference, but the principle issue would seem similar... though `e` gives me even less useful info to go by than `Array`. `:(`

How might I prevent such exceptions here?

Comment: Update: on the [angular gitter](https://gitter.im/angular/angular) @ericmartinez helped me out, noting the DI errors could be prevented by [passing an injector](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCBu0GAfM0kutqOrdiut?p=preview) to `loadAsRoot()`, while actually getting the `NgFor` result to show would require [adding a timeout](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzeBka8ixDEcDIapWt1B?p=preview) to `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in the child component... which even if it works seems like an unfortunate hack, so still trying to figure out whether that's as it should be...

Comment: did you report an issue on github?

Comment: I created https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6444

Comment: Sorry, I was aware of their existing issue. Hope it'll get fixed though; manually calling `detectChanges` works but is pretty annoying. Not to mention hella confusing when you're not yet aware what went wrong or how to address it...