# How to set dynamic id in *ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic2

How to set dynamic `id` in Angular 2?

I have tried:

```
<div class = "CirclePoint" *ngFor="#c of circles" id = "{{ 'Location' + c.id }}"></div>

this.circles = [
        { x: 50 , y: 50 ,id : "oyut1" },
        { x: 100 , y: 100 ,id : "oyut3"  },
        { x: 150 , y: 150 ,id : "oyut2"  }
];
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
<div class = "CirclePoint" *ngFor="let c of circles" 
    [attr.id]="'Location' + c.id">
</div>

<div class = "CirclePoint" *ngFor="let c of circles" 
    attr.id="Location{{c.id}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I thought there were a few common attributes with special treatment but maybe I mixed something up.

Answer (score 21):

This also will work:

```
<div class = "CirclePoint" *ngFor="let c of circles">
   <div [id]="c.id"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to add a prefix, say "loc";

```
<div class = "CirclePoint" *ngFor="let c of circles">
   <div [id]="'loc' + c.id"></div>
</div>
```

Using [] helps to add values dynamically.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
 <div class = "CirclePoint" *ngFor="let c of circles">
     <div id="location_{{c.id}}">write something which you want like c.x </div>
 </div>`
```

Hopefully this will work for you. I searched StackOverflow and I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982258/angular-2-dynamic-template-variable-names-for-dynamiccomponentloader).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i am working on  angular2 "ng-attr-id" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: sorry i don't work in angular2 without see tag, I response you.I found some answer from net

Answer (score 1):

> INDEX CAN BE USED AS DYNAMIC ID

```
<div class="test" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
<div class="function_div" (click)="test(i);">Test Button </div>
    {{item}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the component tag instead of the usual `id="#c"` use `[id]="#c"`. This also applies to dynamic class names. See example below:

```
<div class = "CirlePoit" *ngFor="#c of circles" [id] = "#c"> </div>
```