# Angular 2 rc4: DynamicComponentLoader deprecated

Tags: dynamic, angular

I am upgrading my Angular 2 application for beta.14 to rc.4.

I get a deprecated warning on DynamicComponentLoader in @angular/core.

What is the new Class to be used?
Are there any examples available?

Comment: *Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37044960/1679310*

Comment: From the commit it says "`DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated. Use `ComponentResolver` and `ViewContainerRef` directly." https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5297c9d9ccc6f8831d1656915e3d78e767022517

example http://plnkr.co/edit/8o9dAcOQ4LTYa4Oms5wE?p=preview

Comment: better example: https://github.com/PulpoWork/angular2-inner-content/blob/master/src/inner-content.ts

Answer (score 3):

It has been deprecated. Instead `ComponentResolver` is used. Refer the first answer in this link  [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#).

Refer this too : http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2/

Comment: ComponentResolver has also been removed. https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/73a9ee4

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular