# export 'DynamicComponentLoader' was not found in '@angular/core

Tags: angular, golden-layout

I am new to angular2 ( even don't know angular). In was working with [golden layout](https://golden-layout.com/) and [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/).

I need to use `DynamicComponentLoader` so I used:

```
import {ApplicationRef, Directive, ElementRef, Input, DynamicComponentLoader, ComponentRef, Injector} from '@angular/core';
```

But I am getting an error as:

> 89:151-173 "export 'DynamicComponentLoader' was not found in '@angular/core'

So, how can I import this? Do I need to add it from somewhere?

I also don't understand the difference in importing from `@angular/core` and importing from `angular2/core`. (sorry if this sounds stupid), but I see some projects use 'angular2/core' while some '@angular.core'. Can we sue both? because `DynamicComponentLoader` is available in `angular2/core`.

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` has been deprecated. see here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332249/angular-2-rc4-dynamiccomponentloader-deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @Pengyy. But it is available in angular2/core. What actually the difference?

Comment: imports like `angular2/core` is deprecated since  2.0.0-rc.0 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02 It can be good to see the change logs in these kinds of things, since old tutos might use deprecated stuff :)