# How should I set collectionSize of a ngb-pagination element when using a fillter?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

How can I access the collectionSize when using a filter

```
    <tr *ngFor="let t of types | generalfilter:filter 
          | slice:(page-1)*itemsPerPage:page*itemsPerPage">
```

in a way that number of filtered items is visible within the ngb-pagination ?

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="????"
```

Comment: The solution is in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073671/how-to-find-the-count-of-items-in-an-ngfor-after-the-pipes-have-been-applied

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get this data from your backend. I do this by sending collectionSize in JSON format from backend to front end. So I do it this way in PHP:

```
$data['collectionSize'] = $num_rows; //$num_rows stands for the number of rows in DB
echo json_encode($data);
```

I subscribe to the Observable and assign the value to `collectionSize` in Angular, like so:

```
this.myService.getData()
.subscribe( response => { this.collectionSize = response.collectionSize; } );
```