# How to get count of *ngFor array in COMPONENT file

Tags: angular, data-binding, frontend, ngfor

How to bind variable `c` (count of data items) with variable in **component.ts** file?

In HTML file: 
`<tr *ngFor="let entry of data; let c = count>`

In component.ts file:

```
if (c > 5) ... else ...
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's suppose that `data` is dynamically generated so we can't use `data` in our component. Only thing I want to accomplish is to use `c` in component file.

It's NOT DUPLICATE of this: [Gunters solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076654/7568895) I want clear data binding, without relying on generated DOM.

**UPDATE:** Real scenario is more complex, I didn't want to add it in order to keep focus on above question, but because someone asked for it, it's here:

In HTML file:
    `<tr *ngFor="let entry of data | someFilter; let c = count>`

In component.ts:
    if (c > 5) ... // c here is the count of data items after data is filtered

Yes, I know I can manually trigger `someFilter` in component code and then count number of data items, but that's not preferable solution when you have pipes.

Comment: Can you provide some code showing what you are asking to make things more clear?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I have edited my question, look after "UPDATED" section. The thing is I am using filter on for loop, so I can't get count of items iterated in component.ts file.

Comment: I've never used a regular DOM node, but did you see if you can use `ViewChildren` to get a reference to the `<tr>` nodes? Like this `@ViewChildren('tr') tableRows: QueryList<any>`. If that works you can watch for changes to that and get the length that way

Answer (score 1):

Well, I supouse you can use some like:

```
<div *ngFor=".......;let i=index;let last=last;">
  <!--put here your data-->
  <ng-container *ngIf="last">
       Total Count {{i+1}}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

But I think that is almost "bizarro". I go on thinking that the best approach is have two variables: data and dataFiltered, calculate dataFiltered and make the *ngFor over the dataFilteres.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a varable `c` in your **component.ts**

```
c = arrayName.length;
```

Or you can do it in html directly too.

```
<span>Count: {{arrayName.length}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another pipe after your filtering pipe "someFilter", count elements and store the result in a service. Then it can be accessed from anywhere.

```
transform(input: Model[]): Model[] {
    if (input && this.myService.count !== input.length) {
        this.myService.count = input.length;
    }

    return input;
}
```