# Angular 4: setting the local variable # dynamically

Tags: angular

Is there a way to dynamically set the #id, the HTML attribute that angular uses to construct the @ViewChild element reference?

Specific need: i have the following template, created by iterating through *ngFor, and i wanted to assign the Angular id on the iteration.

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let link of links">
  </li>
</ul>
```

And after it gets interpreted, end up with something like:

```
<ul>
  <li #link1>
   </li>
  <li #link2>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Now I know of many other ways to get the elements, i can assign the # to the ul element, etc, etc, but wondering on whether there is a way to do it on the ngFor.

**EDIT AFTER SEEING THE ANSWERS AND TRYING OUT COMBINATIONS:**

There doesn't seem to be a way to assign distinct local variable identifiers to the single elements generated by *ngFor. 
You can either get them all, like the accepted answer suggests, or just get the parent element, and find your way from there.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35257455/1009922).

Comment: Can we do this the other way around? Meaning, can we dynamically add a template reference variable to a dynamically created DOM element?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Despite the seeming resemblance between regular variables and `#`, multiple elements can be assigned to single local template reference variable:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let link of links" #linkRef></li>
</ul>
```

Which can be obtained with:

```
@ViewChildren('linkRef') linkRefs;
```

Comment: tried this, and it references just the first <li> element.

Comment: @amy8374 it certainly [doesn't](http://plnkr.co/edit/cDEE2S3B27a3EvOrTfhH?p=preview). ViewChild references single element. ViewChildren references multiple.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this code:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;" #itemRef{{i}}>{{item.xyz}}</li>
</ul>
```

Look this question:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977271/create-dynamic-anchorname-components-with-componentresolver-and-ngfor-in-angular)

Comment: @amy8374 It working,But you cannot use `@ViewChild` get it and must use `@ViewChildren`.

Answer (score -6):

You can use the index for it.

```
 <ul>
<li *ngFor="let link of links; let i=index;">
{{link.title}}{{i}} 
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want to set the # not append to the text of <li>