# Angular 6 dynamically add template reference

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a form in Angular 6 which has a list of YouTube links and the type. I have an `*ngFor` to create the list of input fields but i cannot add validation to them.

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index;">
    <label [ngClass]="{ 'invalid': videoUrl.touched && videoUrl.invalid }">
      <i class="icon-youtube"></i>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="video-url" 
        #videoUrl="ngModel" 
        placeholder="Paste YouTube video link here" 
        [(ngModel)]="link.url" 
        required 
        pattern="[0-9]+">
    </label>
    <ul class="validation">
      <li *ngIf="videoUrl.errors.required">
        This field is required, please paste a valid video link.
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="videoUrl.errors.pattern">
        Video link is invalid, check the link again and retry.
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Since the fields are inside an `*ngFor` i don't know how to create the `#videoUrl` reference an array.

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: have you tried this before [Angular 4: setting the local variable # dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47935633/9775003)

Comment: @Sanoj_V any chance you could show me how to integrate that in my code please ?