# How can I have dynamic templateUrl for Angular2 Component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I wanted to load component `templateUrl` based on value passed from parent component. I know tt can be pass through `property binding` to component by have `@Input`, I gave example below in which `myHtml` will be passed as `templateName`.

.But there is no ability to access `@Input` value inside `templateUrl` function. I think `templateUrl` is the first thing going to evaluate by asking for HTML, after that all other component code gets executed.

Like in angular 1 has ability to pass some value from attribute, & then I can use that value inside `templateUrl` function as a parameter like below.

```
templateUrl: function(element, attrs){
    //was getting value
    return '/app/templates/'+ attrs.myTemplateName + '.html'
}
```

But same thing I can't do in Angular2, as `templateUrl` is strongly typed as `string` so it doesn't take function as an attribute.

Is there a way to achieve this **OR** I missed something simple?

**Edit**

I've already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2) which isn't what I want. In referred answer, it render DOM using `DynamicComponentLoader` which loads another component.

This is not what I wanted, because creating new separate component for having different `templateUrl` doesn't make sense in mine case.

Any idea how do I implement this?

Comment: @MarkRajcok The way I has been done in marked as duplicate answer, created template manually/`assign independant component`. And don't wanted to create a new `component` having different `templateUrl`, it sounds repeatative to me.. please guide me If I still missed something..

Comment: Dynamic templateUrls are not supported, according to the answers to the other question (that's why I originally closed this one).  If you want a dynamic template, I believe you have to use DynamicComponentLoader.  It seems like you're trying to create a generic component of sorts, which can have many different possible templates.  That sounds like a job for a DynamicComponent loader, doesn't it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2

Comment: @MarkRajcok correct, this seems kind of workaround, but that need to have boilerplate code, though thanks for explanation. But in linked answer I saw that for each `templateUrl` I need to create a separate `FakeComponent` for having different templateUrl, so for 3 templateUrl's, I need to create three `FakeComponent`, which isn't sounds good for me(unwanted boilerplate code). I think should be a better way than this. am I thinking in wrong direction?

Comment: @AngelAngel thanks..the suggested answer over the referred link, I already tried that thing before adding question.. Angular2 doesn't have such option to have `function` for `templateUrl`, because `@Component` metadata `templateUrl` property is strongly typed as `string`, I already mentioned the thing in my question. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Been struggling with something similar, but unfortunately you can't do this. Component templates are compiled at runtime. So, basically, I would make a component that compiles other child components (which I actually did)

`DynamicComponentLoader` is beign deprecated. You need to use the [`ComponentResolver`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentResolver-class.html) class to load other components inside the main one, like so:

```ts
function makeComponent( selector, template, ...more )
{
  @Component({ selector: selector, template: template })
  class FakeComponent {}
  return FakeComponent;
}

@Component({ ... })
export class MainCmp implements OnInit
{
  // place to insert
  @ViewChild('viewChild', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewChild: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private compiler: ComponentResolver){}
  // or OnChanges, or event binding.. should work

  ngOnInit()
  {
    // decide on your custom logic here, get you @Input, whatever...

    // and you can actually make some custom dynamic component...
    let childCmp = makeComponent( custom, stuff, here );

    // compile then insert in your location, defined by viewChild
    this.compiler.resolveComponent( childCmp )
      .then( (compFactory:ComponentFactory) => this.viewChild.createComponent(compFactory) )
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like angular 2 does not support anymore this option??

Comment: keeping up to date with new changes in angular2, maybe this link can help: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html