# templateUrl with a function in angular2

Tags: function, templates, dynamic, typescript, angular

Well... in angular 1.x.y is

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
       templateUrl : function(tElement, iAttrs){
           return 'http://' + iAttrs.myDirective // More...
       } 
    }
});
```

But.. In Angular2

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-Directive',
    templateUrl: 'http://???' 
})
class HelloWorld {
}
```

Well, in the [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html) say only a `String`. As it is handled to be a function in angular2 ?

Comment: Use templateUrl: 'http://...'

Comment: Its kind of similar question as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071097/how-can-i-have-dynamic-templateurl-for-angular2-component) with no answer...

Comment: @pixelbits OP wanted to have, dynamic `templateUrl` based on value passed from parent component.. the similar question I asked yesterday but didn't find any answer.. could you looked at my previous comment too.

Comment: Component templates are compiled at runtime in Angular 2 by the Angular Compiler. Therefore you can't choose your template dynamically with a function.
EDIT: You could solve this problem by creating a component, which is using  the [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) to dynamically create a component and then display it within your parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement something similar and my solution was the same as Thomas Gassmann's comment above, so I decided to share.

Currently (angular 4.4.5) @Component decorator only accepts a string, therefore the template is not dynamically compiled like on angularJS. However you can implement multiple components and switch the component dynamically. Example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-templateurl

Comment: The idea, is the templetes in de server say `errors/timeout.html`, `errors/input_error.html` .... Etc