# Request promise as a template in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm considering using non-Angular transport to load templates asynchronously (actually I would like to decide on build time if the template is a string or a promise coming from the request), like

```
@Component({
    directives: [],
    selector: 'some',
    template: System.import('./some-template!text')
})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

Can a promise (coming from request) be provided as component template?

Is there some kind of `templateProvider` functionality for directives/components?

Comment: are you talking about relative path of `templateUrl` ?

Comment: @PardeepJain I'm considering a replacement for templateUrl because I would like to decide if the template is loaded synchronously (with `require`) or asynchronously (with `System.import`) on build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of template is string, [see source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/core/src/metadata.ts#L206).

Alternatively you can use

```ts
templateUrl: 'relative/path/from/index.html/some-template.html'
```

---

I tried to do the impossible with `IIFE` and `System.import` with [no luck.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENjDOHMZhGiOutOjDHkd)

You can try with `IIFE` and your own module loader to load `templates` `synchronously`. `asynchronously` I don't think would work.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075861/templateurl-with-a-function-in-angular2/36077756#36077756), why you have to use `IIFE`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to ComponentMetadataFactory, haven't found it by myself. As for IIFE, it shouldn't be here, because System.import returns a promise, not a function.

Comment: You're welcome...  I see, my bad, never used `System.import` before