# Dymanic templateUrl as view handler

Tags: angular

I've recently started picking up angular2 and I'm developing a simple navegation web app. I want to press an option in a nav-menu and a div will update with a diferent html file as the user chooses.

I'm having trouble with the last part.

This is my page layout:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                     header                                |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
|                 |                                         |
|                 |         my-content-area                 |
|    menu         |                                         |
|                 |                                         |
|                 |                                         |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
|                    footer                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've got the click event updating correctly, however I'm having touble with the templateUrl, as I can't get it to be dyanmic and the answers I keep finding are very complicated to the simple design I have (I want to keep this as simple as possible).

This is my `nav-details.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavOption } from './nav.option';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-content-area',
  templateUrl: '{{ navoption.view_name }}'
})

export class NavDetailComponent {
  @Input()
  navoption: NavOption;
}
```

This does not work, as I get a 404 error saying that the file `{{ navoption.view_name }}` can't be found instead of the value of the variable with the path name.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the wrong approach. To change your content view it's best to use Component Routing.
The metadata in the `@Component`decorator isn't dynamic.

So you can't change the template of your DetailComponent but you can change the Component itself.

So you would have 2 different Components then which contain your 2 different templates.

Your `app.component.html` should similar to this.

```
<your-header-component>Header</your-header-component>
<your-menu-component>Menu</your-menu-component>

<router-outlet></router-outlet> // in the router-outlet directive your active component will be placed.

<your-footer-component></your-footer-component>
```

Then you have your `app.module.ts` which contains your Routes too.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        YourHeaderComponent,
        YourMenuComponent,
        YourFooterComponent,
        FooComponent,
        BarComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            {
                path: '',
                component: FooComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'bar',
                component: BarComponent
            }
        ])
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The `FooComponent` and the `BarComponent` are placeholders for your components which you will have in your content area. If the browserroute matches the `bar` path then the `BarComponent` will be placed in the `router-outlet` directive otherwise angular will place the `FooComponent` there.

To change the route via link you have to add the `routerLink`directive to an `a`-tag.

In your `your-menu-component.component.html`

```
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]=''>Foo</a>
    <a [routerLink]='/bar'>Bar</a>
</nav>
```

To read more about angular 2 routing read [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: I am actually following the tutorial on that exact page. I just didn't want to use routing, because I didn't understand that the `@Component` couldn't be dynamic. Thanks for clearing it up.