# angular 2 how to render dynamic templateurl based on certain conditions

Tags: javascript, angular

Are there any example as to render different template in a single component based on certain conditions being fulfilled?

given route '/app', i want to render component/template A if the user A is logged in, and render component/template B if user B is logged in

Comment: The simplest solution would be using the conditions inside one template/component. Example: `*ngIf=getUserRole()`.

Comment: *You should not miss this [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310)*

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution for this approach is just to use `expressions` in your template in order to display different content.

For example in your component:

```
<div *ngIf="userLoggedIn">
  Something
</div>

<div *ngIf="!userLoggedIn">
  Something Else
</div>
```

There are some tother approaches like in this questions [Dynamic template URLs in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2) but it has to do with what exactly you want to show.

If you add a working fiddle/example I can update my answer further.

Answer (score 0):

1- install this library

npm i -D html-loader

============================================================

2- In webpack.config   use html-loader for html files

```
 { test: /\.html$/,  loaders: ['html-loader']   }
```

============================================================

3- If you use ionic , you can copy webpack.config.js  from the path 
"node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js"
then add the html loader to it

=============================================================

4-If you use ionic
In package.json add these lines

```
"config": { 
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_webpack": "webpack.config.ionic.js" 
  },
```

=============================================================

5-Then you can use it as below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
 // templateUrl:"./login.html"

   template:     function(){
    if(globalVariables.test==2) {

      return require("./login2.html")
    }
    else
    {
      return require("./login.html")
    }
  }(),
})
```

======================================

6-If there is unresolved error  with require function you can put it in  declarations.d.ts file as the below :

declare var require: any;