# Parse string from backend and apply behavior on specific matches

Tags: angular

## Problem

I have a string coming from the backend, like:

```
"HTML has an image element. This element can have an alt attribute."
```

When I display this string in my component template, I would like the user to be able to open a modal by clicking on the words "image" and "alt".

### Solution tried

I create an attribute directive `myDir`, and changed the backend so it returns me the following string:

```
"HTML has an <a href="#image" myDir>image</a> element. This element can have an <a href="#alt" myDir>alt</a> attribute."
```

I know this is bad, to return HTML from the backend, but I didn't know how to do it otherwise.

Unfortunately, it does not work, because the 2 `myDir`directives are not executed.

I found this SO question, which I think is similar, but it has no answer:
[Angular 2 parse dynamic template as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699727/angular-2-parse-dynamic-template-as-string)

How could I solve my issue? Is there another way of solving my issue?

In my example there are only 2 words (image and alt), but I actually have a lot of words in my project.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I could create a pipe which would parse the string, collect links, and apply behavior on them.
I will try that.