# Can Angular have more than one template per component?

Tags: angular

I'm going through the Angular tutorial and can see the usefulness of having a component with more than one template.  e.g.  here's a component with a 'full' and 'min' template

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core'
import { Hero } from './hero'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-detail',
    template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
})
@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-detail-min',
    template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      </label>{{hero.id}}</label>
    </div>
    `
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
    @Input()
    hero: Hero;    
}
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work:  how can I make it work?

Comment: You can't, it would have to be two components, or use e.g. `*ngSwitch` within a single template to toggle two views.

Comment: The questions says more than one template , where as you've also changed the selector , which simply means another component altogether , because even when u're using this component , you'll need to change the selectors.
If you only want to change the template , this is your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that this way. However there are several ways to achieve a similar behavior.

First one is just implementing the logic in a separate class which will be inherited by facade classes. Despite the people having doubts about this method it **works**. See [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FGnFKusBbuoVfmcoxe91?p=preview)

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

class HeroDetailAbstractComponent {
    @Input()
    hero: Hero;    
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-detail',
    template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
})
export class HeroDetailComponent extends HeroDetailAbstractComponent {};

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-detail-min',
    template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      </label>{{hero.id}}</label>
    </div>
    `
})
export class HeroDetailMinComponent extends HeroDetailAbstractComponent {}
```

Another approach is to use another input parameter let's say called `mode`:

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core'
import { Hero } from './hero'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-detail',
    template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero && mode === 'max'">
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="hero && mode === 'min'">
      </label>{{hero.id}}</label>
    </div>
    `
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
    @Input()
    hero: Hero;    

    @Input()
    mode: string; 
}
```

Both methods simply work. I personally prefer the first way because it looks easier to write separate unit tests and it feels more natural.

Comment: The first example would not work if you have decorators , like @Input , in the parent class , you'd need to define those inside the child component as well , which means defining them multiple times .

The only way to handle that issue is to define your own decorator.

Comment: @xe4me that's true. However, the `Input` is not the case when it's coming to the router driven components. Also redeclaring the input is not that complicated process and it could be a good trade for reducing the template complexity

Comment: hmm , not sure , because component easily grow bigger , and Input is not the only one , this would go further to ViewChild , Output and ... . 
I've been there , this would cause heaps of issue as you starting making it more complicated.

Comment: By the way , what exactly do you mean by router driven components ? and how would that be related to Input properties/ ?

Comment: @xe4me agree, for complex components it's a problem. By router driven I mean the components which are loaded by the router, thus they don't have input properties

Comment: @xe4me The first example **WORKS** with `Input` and `ViewChild` decorators (and I am sure with many more decorators as well). Please don't confuse people like that anymore. See the updated answer

Comment: @smnbbrv you're right, it wasn't working before , looks like it's fixed. good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different selectors, it would have to be two components. Alternatively, you could use [the `ngSwitch` directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) do something like:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-detail',
    template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero" *ngSwitch="full">
      <div ngSwitchCase="true">
        <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
        <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div>
          <label>name: </label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ngSwitchDefault>
        <label>{{hero.id}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
    @Input()
    hero: Hero;    

    @Input()
    full: boolean;
}
```

Then include the component as:

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="hero" [full]="true"></my-hero-detail>
```